# HTML5 play pause video on image or video click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I have an HTML5 Video on my page without controls. I use an image over the video (a play icon). I want that the video can play/pause on click over the video or over the icon image.

This is the script I've tried to use but doesn't work:

If I click over the video it works fine, meanwhile if I click on the icon image nothing happens.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'video', '#btnplay', function (e) {
        var video = $(this).get(0);
        if (video.paused === false) {
            video.pause();
            } else {
            video.play();
        }
        return false;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video-container">
  <video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" width="100%" height="auto" class="videohome"> Your browser does not support the video tag. <source src="images/video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" /></video>
  <img id="btnplay" class="playbtn" src="images/play.png" alt="Play">
</div>
```

Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', 'video, #btnplay', function (e) {
        var video = $('video').get(0);  // This line has been updated.
        if (video.paused === false) {
            video.pause();
            } else {
            video.play();
        }
        return false;
    });
```

**Explanation:** There are two changes needed, the two selectors in one inverted comma, and although we click on any of them, get the 'video' element for reference, so instead of $(this).get(0) I changed it to $('video').get(0) so either we click on the icon or click on video tag itself, it always refers to the video tag only.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it doesn't work, also in this case neither the click over the video start to play.

Comment: @DFD, Updated my answer again. Try this out please.

Comment: your welcome @DFD, happy to help. thank you so much for accepting my answer and voting it up.
There are two changes needed, the two selectors in one inverted comma, and although we click on any of them, get the 'video' element for reference, so instead of `$(this).get(0)` I changed it to `$('video').get(0)` so either we click on icon or click on video tag itself, it always referes to the video tag.